# need to achieve auto capturing of images from camera in android

Tags: java, android

Am creating a camera application which need to auto capture the images when the camera is on with out any click, now I have called the camera using the Intent from my application,it's working but auto capturing of images is not implemented in that, I have searched every where could able to get the solution for it please do help me to resolve this issue thanks in advance

Comment: You can use timer to auto capture image.

Comment: @RashiduzzamanKhan could you please post some example code if you don't mind

Comment: Is it Surface View camera or not ?

Comment: @RashiduzzamanKhan no actually am calling through intent not using surface view

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Surface View camera for auto capture image. You can follow this [link](https://github.com/sandipmjadhav/CaptureImage)

Just download and use this source code.

I think it will help you

Add this code:

```
final Handler handle = new Handler();
    final Runnable background = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback,
                        jpegCallback);

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    };

    handle.postDelayed(background, 1000);
```

It will Auto capture after one second

Comment: this will implement auto capture also

Comment: hey I have implemented the surface view camera can you tell me how can I achieve the auto capturing of the images please

Comment: but am getting error am pasting inside the oncreate